# Refactor Ruby method for getting domain?

Tags: ruby, https

How do I make this more Ruby like? I want to return the host, for example
if the URL is "http://www.facebook.com" then I want to get 'facebook.com'.

Any other sub-domains without 'www' should give the subdomin as well.
If  the URL is "http://gist.github.com" then I want 'gist.github.com':

```
def get_domain
  a = @url.split('.')
  a[-1] =  a[-1].gsub(/\//,'')
  if a[0][-3..-1] == "www"
    a.delete_at(0)
  else
    a[0] = a[0].gsub(/https?:\/\//,'')
  end
  domain = a.join('.')
  domain
rescue => e
  puts e.message
end #end of get_domain
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [URI::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'uri'
URI.parse("http://gist.github.com/a/b/c").host.sub(/^www\./, '')
#=> "gist.github.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is looking like a custom requirement. By looking at your code, you want to remove http(s) and www. part of the url

```
def get_custom_domain
  @url.gsub(/^((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?)/, '')
end
```

But it will be better if you give more example of what you exactly want. I have written some specs [here](https://gist.github.com/prathamesh-sonpatki/5045794)
Please update it if i am missing some edge case.

Comment: Parsing urls by hand is risky, for example try this one: `http://user:password@server.org/path/file`.